# Redmine Custom Query to return only specific columns

Tags: redmine, restful-url, redmine-api

How to filter Redmine issues to only include specified columns, when using the REST API xml/json format?

I have a custom query to obtain specific columns of issues:

- Filter set to "status(open)" and "Due Date(any)"
- Options / Selected Columns set to "Due Date" (To only return the ID and the Due Date in the response)

These are two ways of accessing it:

**A** /issues?query_id=myqueryid

**B** /issues.xml?query_id=myqueryid

When i run **A** in my browser, the correct response is given, containing only the id and the due date. In contrast to **B**, now every field (ie. id, description, start date,...) is included in the response.

I also tried to add a "fields" value as some other apis suggest, but to no avail (ie. /issues.xml?issue_id=1337&fields=due_date,etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redmine's REST API (i.e. the JSON and XML APIs) always returns all base fields of filtered issues. You can optionally include *additional* fields like watchers, journals, issue relations, ... by using the `include` mechanism describe in the [API docs](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Showing-an-issue)

When using the API, the client is supposed to fetch any fields it desires from the response on their own. The feature to show a tailored HTML table with selected columns as done in the web UI is considered not very useful for the API use-case right now.